# Using Bootstrap4 and Angular to render nav-tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want for every recipe and its variants a single page to edit.

At the moment, the content will be rendered below(see [here](https://webfreekorni.azurewebsites.net/administrator/product/recipe),=> Click "Erstelle Variante").

This is how it [looks like now](https://ibb.co/0XHPJxx).

I was orientating here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp

The entire overview: [here](https://ibb.co/gRfBZSf).

Here the relevant code snippet:

```
    <div class="tab-content" id="BarRecipe_{{Helper_ReplaceId(selectedRecipe.id)}}">

      <div class="tab-pane container active"  *ngFor="let all of [selectedRecipe].concat(selectedRecipe.relatedRecipes); let i = index" id="menu_{{Helper_ReplaceId(all.id)}}">
        <br />
        {{all.id}}

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block" (click)="onUpdateRecipe()" [disabled]="!f.valid">Speicher Variante</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block " (click)="onDeleteRecipe()">Lösche Variante</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />

      </div>


    </div>
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Couldn't get what you wanna do. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: sure, normally that bootstrap panel should look like this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_tabs_toggleable&stacked=h for each tab you click, you get one result. When I add variants, get get many varaints for each tab, when I click, it is not separated

Comment: you can use ng-bootstrap with angular for bootstrap components. check this out for [tabs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples)